# Why is my Kubernetes service removed at random intervals?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-service, apm

I've created a service with the definition below on AWS EKS.
And although the service works fine, it keeps getting removed.
If been looking for days and can't figure out the reason.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: apm-server-agent-http
   namespace: elastic
annotations:
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 'true'
labels:
   agent.k8s.elastic.co/name: apm-server
   common.k8s.elastic.co/type: agent
spec:
   type: LoadBalancer
   ports:
     - name: http
       protocol: TCP
       port: 8200
       targetPort: 8200
   selector:
     agent.k8s.elastic.co/name: apm-server
     common.k8s.elastic.co/type: agent
```

At the seemingly random intervals I see "Deleting existing load balancer" in the logs.
And the service and AWS ELB are removed.

```
cloud-controller-manager log:
I0317 10:38:59.915132      11 controller.go:398] Deleting existing load balancer for service elastic/apm-server-agent-http
I0317 10:38:59.915305      11 event.go:294] "Event occurred" object="elastic/apm-server-agent-http" fieldPath="" kind="Service" apiVersion="v1" type="Normal" reason="DeletingLoadBalancer" message="Deleting load balancer"
I0317 10:39:00.243274      11 aws.go:4608] Removing rule for traffic from the load balancer (sg-0deedf2f1a2669bdf) to instance (sg-08d19a34311831183)
```

**kube-proxy logs**

```
I0320 07:10:23.747460 1 service.go:324] "Service updated ports" service="elastic/apm-server-agent-http" portCount=1
I0320 07:10:23.747557 1 service.go:440] "Adding new service port" portName="elastic/apm-server-agent-http:http" servicePort="10.100.152.85:8200/TCP"
I0320 07:33:03.393989 1 service.go:324] "Service updated ports" service="elastic/apm-server-agent-http" portCount=0
I0320 07:33:03.394153 1 service.go:465] "Removing service port" portName="elastic/apm-server-agent-http:http"
```

The pod is **running** fine, no restarts

```
kubectl -n elastic get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
apm-server-agent-749c8655c4-6hdsj     1/1     Running   0               18h
```

Any help or pointers to help figure this out is greatly appreciated.

Currently I've added
`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"`
This allows for delete protection on the AWS ELB.
As a result the 'service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup' finalizer blocks the delete.
But the delete is still triggered as you can see in the COUNT below

```
kubectl -n elastic get event -o wide
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON                 OBJECT                          SUBOBJECT   SOURCE               MESSAGE                  FIRST SEEN   COUNT   NAME
3m53s       Normal   DeletingLoadBalancer   service/apm-server-agent-http               service-controller   Deleting load balancer   14h          1853    apm-server-agent-http.17513f505d68f704
```

Comment: Does your company use a policy as code solution (or AWS Config) that periodically scans the environment for policy violations and deletes objects/resources that violate the policy?

Comment: @JeremyCowan No, that's not the case